# Obtener diferencia de fechas entre datos misma columna por estado POSTGRES

Tags: sql, postgresql

Solicito de su ayuda en sacar la diferencia entre 2 fechas a partir del estado, los datos vienen en la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A modo de ejemplo, necesito restar las fechas del estado 1 y 2 del id 3, es decir (26/02/2021 20:57) - (25/02/2021  4:54:41 p. m.), y el resultado debería ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dado que el id 3 es el único que tiene el estado 1 y 2.

Para fines practicos el estado 1=abierto y 2=cerrado, y se quiere identificar **el tiempo que duró un ID.**

Comment: Para dar "solución", realicé una consulta utilizando la sentencia WITH (que me crea unas "tablas"), posteriormente hago una relación con JOIN así: 

WITH a1 AS (select id, estado, fecha_modificacion, usuario from base1 a1 where estado =1),
a2 AS (select id, estado, fecha_modificacion, usuario from base2 a1 where estado =3)
select a1.id, a1.estado, a1.fecha_modificacion, a2.fecha_modificacion, a1.user_name from a1 inner join a2 on a1.id = a2.id;

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacer la query:

```
SELECT t.id, EXTRACT(epoch FROM t2.fecha_modificacion - t.fecha_modificacion) / 3600
FROM t
INNER JOIN t AS t2 ON t.id = t2.id AND t.estado = 1 AND t2.estado = 2;
```

Considerando que solo hay un estado 1 y un esatado 2 por cada id, y se resta la fecha_modificación del estado 2 menos la del estado 1.